# What is an example of a syntactic structure that can't be represented by a BNF grammar?

Tags: syntax, grammar

The tools for working with BNF grammars are a little more discoverable (ANTLR, Gold, etc) and usable than for other types of grammars. What sort of sentences can't be represented with ordinary BNF grammar rules?

Answer (score 7):

On this site, I would expect that this question is about
**linguistically meaningful** examples of syntactic structures that cannot be represented by BNF.

A first minor point is that [BNF](http://cui.unige.ch/isi/bnf/AboutBNF.html) is a programmer/compiler oriented syntax (introduced with the programming language Algol 60) for representing
what should rather be called more abstractedly **context-free grammar** (CFG).

The adequacy of context-free grammars for representing the syntax of
natural languages has been addressed by many people in different way.

It should be also noted that we are mostly talking of a syntactic
infrastructure, based on formal language theory, since linguist often
consider as part of syntax various attribute and features that can be
associated with this syntactic infrastructure.

The most frequently given example of syntactic structure that cannot
be represented by a CF grammar is apparently the **cross-serial
dependency** represented in the following diagram.

[image: cross-serial dependency diagram] (source [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-serial_dependency))

Such a syntactic structure is found in some languages, including Dutch
and Swiss-German. Here is a Swiss-German example from Stuart Shieber:

```
                             _____________________
             _______________|______________       |
            |               |              |      |
...mer  em Hans     es    huus          hälfed  aastriiche.
...we   Hans (dat)  the   house (acc)   helped  paint.
```

That is, "we helped Hans paint the house."

Now there are to ways in which context-freeness of a language may be analyzed:

- **strong context-freeness**: can this language be generated by a CF grammar so that the
  parse-tree structure conforms the syntactic relations between the
  parts of speech?
- **weak context-freeness**: can the language be analyzed by a CF grammar at all? However, if the language is not strongly
  context-free, the structure of the parse-trees will not reflect the
  proper syntactic organization of a parsed sentence. But then, it is usually possible to retrieve it by other means, once the parsing is done.

It has been observed since around 1982 that cross-serial dependency is
not strongly context-free, which is rather obvious. But there was some
debate regarding weak context-freeness of languages with cross-serial
dependency. The usual example was cross-serial dependency in Dutch, but there were arguments to show that Dutch was still weakly context-free.

In 1985, Stuart Shieber used the case of Swiss-German cross-serial
dependency as evidence of a weakly non-context-free natural language.
He used explicit case marking of the language and case based ordering
rules for subordinate clauses to show that (the cross-serial part of)
the language is weakly context-free only if the language of strings of the
form {*w a^m b^n x c^m d^n y | n,m* >0} where *a, b, c* and *d* are symbols,
*w,x,y* are strings not including these symbols, and *a^m* means a
repeated *m* times.

But this language is known to be weakly non-context-free, as can
easily be shown with the pumping lemma.

However, cross-serial dependency can be handled, in the strong structural sense, by a slightly more complex formalism, the [tree-adjoining grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree-adjoining_grammar).

There is actually a detailed account of this topic (which I found after
writing this answer) written by Johan Behrenfeldt  as his MS thesis in
2009.

---

Additional note:

Other candidates for non-context-freeness are the **free word order
languages**. It is not a type of syntax I know well, but I think it
should be mentioned. This case is complicated by the fact that some
languages have partially free [word order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order).

Though there has been significant work to encode free word
order into the context-free framework, one may wonder whether it is
always really meaningful structurally.  The point is that full free word order
amounts to considering strings as unordered sets of words. This
implies a much greater combinatorics for associating the words,
potentially giving rise to exponential algorithms rather polynomial
ones, as is the case for context-free parsing, which is cubic. This can be
dealt with by using other information in the parts of speech (morphological marking), through
different kinds of algorithms with tractable complexity, and some have been proposed (see 4th reference).

Of course, if there are no constraints on word order (or limited
ones), the language may well be regular, hence weakly context-free.
But, in this case, there is little hope to use information from the
context-free parsing (there is none for a regular grammar) to
recreate a syntactic structure for the sentence being analyzed. Weak
context-freeness does not help.

References:

- Stuart Shieber, [Evidence against the context-freeness of natural
  language](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~shieber/Biblio/Papers/shieber85.pdf), *Linguistics and philosophy*, 8, 1985, 333-343.
- Johan Behrenfeldt. *[A Linguist's Survey of Pumping Lemmata](http://www.flov.gu.se/digitalAssets/1302/1302983_behrenfeldt-johan-alinguists.pdf)*, MS thesis,
  Univ. of Gothenburg, June 2009.
- Carl Vogel, Ulrike Hahn, Holly Branigan, [Cross-Serial Dependencies Are Not Hard to Process](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/C/C96/C96-1028.pdf). *COLING 1996*: 157-162.
- Akshar Bharati, Rajeev Sangal, 
  [Parsing Free Word Order Languages in the Paninian Framework](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P93/P93-1015.pdf),
  ACL 1993.

Comment: thanks for this explaination. do you have any idea about http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2284/is-it-possible-to-identify-different-queries-questions-in-sentence

Comment: @user2129623 You're welcome. Why do you expect me to be competent on that question?

Answer (score 5):

BNF is a Type-2 language in the [Chomsky Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).
A context free grammar has rules of the type:

```
A -> B C
```

but not rules of the type:

```
x A y -> x B C y
```

i.e., what happens with A depends on what comes before or after A (A's context).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar) has a Type-1 example which I don't know how to write here. [Feel free to edit this post.]

[Thue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_%28programming_language%29) is a Type-0 language which also cannot be represented in BNF.

As a realistic example, many natural languages require that the formal grammar used to analyse them be [Mildly context-sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mildly_context-sensitive_language).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the intersection of the outputs of two context-free languages is not necessarily context free.  So (a raised to power x) (b ... x) (c ... y) intersected with 
(a ... z) (b ... x) (c ... x) produces (a ... x) (b ... x) (c ... x) because of the identity relation of the two b expressions, a result that is context-sensitive.  (Sorry I can't write it in standard mathematical notation.)